# Using Python's Pip in Virtualenv

Tags: python, heroku, virtualenv, pip

I have been using Heroku's cedar stack with Python for some time now, without any errors. Today, however, when I decided to update my dependencies *locally*, within my `virtualenv` via `sudo bin/pip install -r requirements` I received the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/dev/warren/warren/bin/pip", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/dev/warren/warren/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 698, in <module>
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/dev/warren/warren/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 701, in Environment
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/dev/warren/warren/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 96, in get_supported_platform
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/dev/warren/warren/lib/python2.6/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.6.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 221, in get_build_platform
  File "/Users/alex/Desktop/dev/warren/warren/lib/python2.6/distutils/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    exec(open(os.path.join(distutils_path, '__init__.py')).read())
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/distutils/__init__.py'
```

I suspected this had something to do with my upgrade to Lion (as pointed out by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3129852/python-cant-locate-distutils-path-on-mac-osx)), but as mentioned in that question I have also updated Xcode, but the problem persists.

When I try to `cd` into the above directory there is no `__init__.py` file, in fact there is no `.py` files at all, just `.pyo` and `.pyc` files.

Comment: What was the command line used to run virtualenv ?

Comment: Try without "sudo". You dont need root privileges inside virtualenv.

Comment: @DenisKabalkin I receive the error each time I run `pip`.

Comment: Also how was the virtual env created - what flags did you pass in? and was distribute installed in the virtualenv or the System?

Comment: @Mark It was originally created like so `virtualenv --no-site-packages .` following [this guide](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python).

Comment: The last error is important. There must be a `__init__.py` file in the distutils directory, otherwise the distutils package does not exist (`__init__.py` define that a directory is a package). Maybe the python install is not quite right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message you're receiving is due to the link you that virtualenv created to your system python. You'll now want to destroy the virtualenv and recreate it. To destroy it you'll  want to:

```
rm -r bin
rm -r include
rm -r lib
rm .Python
```

Then you should be able to re-create your virtualenv and then pip install your requirements.txt